# EmEditor js macro: is it possible to suppress temporary updates in the editor?

Tags: javascript, macros, emeditor

I often write EmEditor macros with a lot of steps. In running such a long macro, content in the editor window would flash to update frequently.

Is it possible to suppress all temporary updates and directly show the final result in the editor window? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this on begin

**Redraw = false;**

This parameter stops the automatic refresh after an instruction that causes a display update, the refresh is only performed again at the end of the macro or until the user sets the parameter to true.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).